# using value of html input type month in mysql where clause

Tags: php, mysql

I have a HTML input type month, like

```
<input name="month" type="month" />
```

query

```
$bywherecls="WHERE DATE_FORMAT(fromdate, '%Y %m') = '".$_GET['month']."'";
```

value of `$_GET['month']` is like `2016-08`

what is wrong with the query above?

Comment: can you be more precise on the thing to fix please?
the type "month" will return 2016-08 as it is it's behaviour.

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because `$_GET` data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format should be `%Y-%m`, not `%y %m`.
With your current code you are checking `WHERE 'YYYY MM' = '2016-08'`, which will never return any results.

```
$bywherecls="WHERE DATE_FORMAT(fromdate, '%Y-%m') = '".$_GET['month']."'";
```

> And you **should never** send data directly from the user to the database. use some [escape](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-escape-string.php) function or use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php).

Comment: where am I using `%y %m`?